# Using PhoneGaps' iOS Simulator to store files using File API - Where are they stored?

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator, phonegap-plugins

I am storing on local storage and it says root folder is "/". When doing a fileread, I can see the different folders and files that I have created, but I cannot seem to find them anywhere on my local hard drive. I am using the iOS simulator. I have already checked the www folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `PERSISTENT` option they are stored on the Documents folder, if you use the `TEMPORARY` option they are stored on the Caches folder.

To see the files on the hard drive open a new finder window, on the menu press go, then press alt key and library option will appear, press the library option, then go to Application Support folder, then iPhone simulator folder, the OS version of the simulator where you tested, Applications, and search the app between all the installed apps